# New server registration - The network path was not found

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a new instance of Sql server but this error always occurs. I found nothing helpful about this. I have no problems when I try to connect to the existing servers, it only happens when I try to create a new instance.

[image: Link-to-Image]

Comment: what do you mean by `Try to create a new instance of sql Server` ? Have you installed sql server with an instance name ?

Comment: A new registration does not create a new SQL Server instance. A new instance is typically created by running the SQL Server setup utility.  The newly created instance can then be subsequently registered.

Comment: I run mssql on a server instance wich type is Windows Authentication. The reason why I'm trying to create another instance is cuz I need the type to be SQL Server Authentification. I knew that an instance can be created from Setup but I was looking for another way cuz I found it a little pointless to run it every time I need a new one.